# Field Population (ReviewBoard code)

Tags: python, review-board

I'm am making custom modifications to ReviewBoard (RBtools); however, I can't seem to understand what Python is doing implicitly at this step.

I am trying to understand where `ReviewBoardServer` sets its value for `self.info.path`.

I stepped through the debugger and traced it to the `method check_api_version` on the line

```
self.root_resource = root_resource
```

Prior to this statement, we have `self.info` as `None`, but it quickly changes to an `SVNRepositoryInfo` after the line above.

The line above does not set the class field of `self.info` in that line. I am guessing that Python is doing something under the hood that allows it to populate `self._info` by setting `self.root_resource`? Is this correct? If so, where would I find more information about this?

For reference the init method looks like:

```
 185 class ReviewBoardServer(object):
 186     """
 187     An instance of a Review Board server.
 188     """
 189     def __init__(self, url, info, cookie_file):
 190         self.url = url
 191         if self.url[-1] != '/':
 192             self.url += '/'
 193         self._info = info
 194         self._server_info = None
 195         self.capabilities = None
 196         self.root_resource = None
 197         self.deprecated_api = False
 198         self.rb_version = "0.0.0.0"
 199         self.cookie_file = cookie_file
 200         self.cookie_jar  = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(self.cookie_file)
 201         self.deprecated_api = False
 202         self.root_resource = None
```

For reference, the specific file is hosted on Github below:
https://github.com/reviewboard/rbtools/blob/release-0.4.3/rbtools/postreview.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do things like that "under the hood" in Python using descriptors along with the built-in[`property()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=property#property) function. 
See [*Implementing Descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) in the documentation for more details.

The`postreview.py`source file has the line:

```
627     info = property(_get_server_info)
```

Which defines a`__get__()`function for the`ReviewBoardServer`class attribute named`info`.

The definition of`_get_server_info()`is right above that in the source:

```
def _get_server_info(self):
    if not self._server_info:
        self._server_info = self._info.find_server_repository_info(self)

    return self._server_info
```

As you can see, whenever the value of`info`is retrieved, if the value of`self._server_info`is`None`, it is set to something and then its value is returned as the value of the attribute.